# regular expression to extract ID from string in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a URL like this

```
http://www.sample.com/mens-ski-jackets/dusk-printed-ski-jacket-p8654.aspx?popup=1
```

and i need to extract productId from this URL using jquery which is `8654`. productId should always be after `p` like this `p8654`

i do not have any clue on where to start hence no code provided..

please help.

Thanks

Comment: `var id = url.split('.asp').shift().split('-p').pop();`

Answer (score 3):

I think a simple regex should do like

```
var url = 'http://www.sample.com/mens-ski-jackets/dusk-printed-ski-jacket-p8654.aspx?popup=1'; 
var id = url.match(/p(\d+)\.aspx/)[1]
```